# Is there any way to handle ISO-8859-16 / latin10 encoded files in vim?

Tags: vim, character-encoding

From the help page section `encoding-values`:

```
Supported 'encoding' values are:            *encoding-values*
1   latin1  8-bit characters (ISO 8859-1, also used for cp1252)
1   iso-8859-n  ISO_8859 variant (n = 2 to 15)
[...]
```

Somehow, it seems that ISO-8859-16 / latin10 was left out? I fail to read files with that encoding correctly. Am I overlooking anything? If not, can I somehow add support for this character encoding to vim through a plugin or so?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, my version of Vim is compiled with +iconv/dyn. According to the Vim documentation:

> On MS-Windows Vim can be compiled with the +iconv/dyn feature.  This
>   means Vim will search for the "iconv.dll" and "libiconv.dll"
>   libraries.  When neither of them can be found Vim will still work but
>   some conversions won't be possible.

The most recent version from the DLL from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/gettext/files/libiconv-win32/ seems to do job for me. Without it I could not convert most iso-8859 encodings other than iso-8859-1. Having iconv.dll installed I can load the files easily with:

`:e ++enc=iso-8859-16 file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If Vim cannot handle it, you can convert to (for example) UTF-8) with the `iconv` tool:

```
$ iconv --from-code ISO-8859-16 --to-code UTF-8 -o outputfile inputfile
```

Comment: I'm aware of that and using iconv to convert back and forth is my current approach. Not very convenient though.

Comment: Well, if you've determined that Vim doesn't handle that encoding yet (but think it should), ask for such support on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php).